# hadoop ,setting JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh

Tags: java, hadoop

i'm using windows8 64 bit , i've already gone through most of the tutorials over the internet , other questions and suggestion here in stackoverflow , but nothing seems to fix it .
my java is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 and here is my entry in hadoop-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"

i'm using hadoop-2.2.0
and this is the error message :
 /bin/java: No such file or directoryes\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directoryk1.7.0_25

Edit :i know it is a path problem .
i've tried :

c:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

cygdrive\c\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

and nearly every other variation but with no luck .

Comment: The error message that you've pasted has munged paths in it.

Comment: could u kindly explain more ?

Comment: You pasted an error message containing bad paths.  Look at it carefully.  Either you pasted it incorrectly (which seems unlikely), or the paths are actually bad.  Find out why they're bad, and you've solved your problem.

Comment: i know it is because a bad path , the thing is , i don't know the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop does not work on windows platform, it is fully support linux, unix, and Mac. use ubunto instead

Comment: i think it "can work " on windows ,the thing is , i'm using it "only"because some of the mahout's functionality depends on it .but i'm not interested - at least for now- to use hadoop fully .